# Git detached head after pull/push fail

Tags: git, heroku, github

The problem was seemingly a pretty standard issue caused by a discrepancy between the remote branch and a local CSS file I was pushing to git.

I received the standard error message that "Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind." Ok, no worries. I used a `git pull origin master` and then -- after pulling -- moved onto my git push.

The push was successful to the master branch with no error message. Thinking everything was great, I then used `git push heroku master` and receive an error only when pushing to Heroku:

```
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

I am perplexed, as I am seeing that the working directory is clean through `git status` (and presumably the HEAD is attached), yet the Heroku push continues to indicate that there is conflict in the remote/local files.

Any ideas on what I need to do for it to recognize the conflict has been resolved for Heroku just as I did with Git?

EDIT: One detail I forgot to share. I have used `git checkout master` to confirm that I am on the master branch, so we're definitely good there.

Comment: `git diff heroku/master` will show you the difference.

Comment: Why does the title mention "detached HEAD" while your message doesn't talk about this at all? It seems you have two remotes (origin and heroku), you pulled from origin and you're trying to push to heroku, which is ahead of origin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the issue was not a detached head, as I anticipated. Like Matthieu mentions, my mistake was in thinking that I was up to date because the origin repo was reading that it had been committed/merged.

Because Heroku is a separate remote, seeing that my pull/push for the origin remote completely missed the important question (hence my confusion): is the Heroku remote updated?

To do that, I ran `git push heroku master -f` and that brought the second remote up to speed, and we're back in action.